# Newbie Hypervisor Questions

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

1. If I install a bare-metal hypervisor (say, ESXi), would it allow me to run Windows 7 concurrently with Linux?
2. Would it allow me to run multiple instances of Windows 7?
3. When I'm sitting at the PC that's running Win7 and Linux on a hypervisor, which OS do I see when I look at the screen?  (I'm suspecting that the only way to access either OS is to do a remote login.)
4. Assuming the answer to #2 is yes, how do you manage multiple installs of Win7 on the same hard drive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give your title more description to the actual questions instead of the experience of the questions you are about to ask. This help people who have the same question find this question on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to run Linux and Windows in parallel you may of course do this on e.g. ESXi. Still, the OSes would run with virtualized (or emulated) hardware available to them, i.e. you would not be able to easily access all the hardware directly and the hypervisor itself not only introduces an overhead but this overhead is not deterministic.
If you want to run an RTOS (like Real-Time Linux) or any other RTOS, then you need a "real-time hypervisor".
You can google for such hypervisors - there are a few out there.
(I dont want to recommend one here as we are a vendor of such a solution our selves)
Regards
GFL

Comment: Thank you for the info (and another question:  Are real-time hypervisors limited to supporting real-time OSs?  (Would it make sense, say from a performance aspect, to run Win7 on top of an RT hypervisor?)

Comment: Yes, this is a very typical use case for a real-time hypervisor. Consolidating hardware by running e.g. Win7 for HMI and an RTOS for control on a single platform where otherwise you would normally need multiple boards. Of course you could also just run multiple instances of an RTOS but on x86 the majority use Windows with Linux, VxWorks, QNX, Windows CE or other RTOSes.